# Invalid argument supplied for foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

My code is supposed to display validation errors while logging in/signing in, but for some reason, it gives me:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 28
```

Im not sure how to fix this, im pretty sure I did everything right. Heres the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="first.php" method="post">
Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br />
Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit"><br />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$errors = array();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if(!isset($username) || empty($username)){
    $errors = "Empty username<br />";
}
if ($username = $password){
    $errors = "Username cannot match password";
}
if ($username > 10){

    $errors['username'] = "Username out of range<br />";
}
if (!empty($errors)){
echo "<div class=\"error\">";
echo "Please fix the following errors:";
echo "<ul>";
foreach($errors as $key => $error){
echo "<li>{$error}</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

PLEASE dont give me the entire code back, just give me the parts(s) that are wrong and tell me where they go and why!

Comment: Compare your assignments: `$errors = "Username cannot match password";` and `$errors['username'] = "Username out of range<br />";` see the difference? And also `=`, `==` are different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($username = $password){
    $errors = "Username cannot match password";
}
```

You use the assignment operator (`=`), not the comparison operator (`==`). This will always evaluate to `true`, meaning `$errors` is always a string.

Since it's a string and it's not empty, it goes into `foreach`, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
$errors = "Empty username<br />";
```

The above sets `$errors` to string. You can not iterate a string with a foreach loop, hence the error.

Instead, replace the line with:

```
$errors['username'] = "Empty username<br />"
```

Also. your if condition will always pass, as you have incorrectly used the assignment `=` operator instead of equality operator. Change that to:

```
if ($username == $password){
```